# Problem in playing audio file using media player

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

Here is the code for the button which should start and pause the audio.
I have checked the button-text == "start" or "pause" and change the text and use the appropriate methods accordingly
i.e mediaplayer.start() and mediaplayer.pause().
But still, the audio won't play.

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 

{
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;//Mediaplayer
Button button;
public void start(View view)
{
    String text = button.getText().toString();
    if (text == "start") 
    {
        mediaPlayer.start(); //starting the audio
        button.setText("pause");
    } 
    else 
    {
        mediaPlayer.pause(); //pausing the audio
        button.setText("start");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button =  findViewById(R.id.start);
    mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.music);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps you should try:
First, try this because I think It gives always a false condition:

```
if(text.trim().equals("start"))
```

If Still not work Try this one:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 

    {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;//Mediaplayer
    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button =  findViewById(R.id.start);
        mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.music);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

        String text = button.getText().toString().trim();
        if (text.equals("start")) 
        {
            mediaPlayer.start(); 
            button.setText("pause");
        } 
        else 
        {
            mediaPlayer.pause(); 
            button.setText("start");
        }

      }
    }
} }
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, this worked but still i dont why. Can you explain what was wrong in my code

Comment: actually, .trim() just remove the spaces. v o t e u p